# How can I test IE10 on Mac?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer-10

How can I test web sites in IE10 on Mac?

Currently I am testing IE9 in VirtualBox with Windows 7 installed from [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575). I could not find similar image for Windows 8. [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) does not have IE10 eigher. Is there an easy way to test IE10 on Mac?

Comment: How are you using VPC images on a Mac?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox to run those PVC images on Mac OS

Comment: If you have a solution of your own, please post it as an answer and mark that answer accepted instead of mine. (For that matter, why do you even need to install Windows 7 separately? The link I provided gives you entire Windows ISOs to use.)

Comment: +1 BoltClock, @evgeny you should read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That page no longer appears to be up-to-date.

However, Microsoft's developer website provides [free download links](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) to test [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge) and Internet Explorer (versions 8 through 11) using virtual machines. You can manage them locally using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or another virtualization software tool.

Comment: +1 on the Modernie VMs I wrote a blog post to get you started, http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2013/05/29/You-Don_2700_t-Need-Windows-To-Test-Your-Web-Site-in-Internet-Explorer.aspx

Comment: LOL it had no traffic anymore :) Plus the Edge team changed their portal. This is the latest link. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Safari and navigate to **Safari > Preferences** from the menu bar.
2. Click on the **Advanced** tab.
3. Check the **"Show Develop menu in menu bar"** setting, then close the Preferences window.
4. The **Develop** **menu** should now show in your menu bar.
5. Go to **Develop > User Agent**.
6. Here, you have to option to choose different browser options like ***Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, 10*** and ***11***. You can also choose ***Firefox*** and ***Chrome*** as the **User Agent**.

*Source*: [How to view websites on your Mac that require Internet Explorer (or a PC)](https://www.imore.com/how-view-websites-your-mac-require-internet-explorer-or-pc)

Comment: In the modern world, this is the easiest possible way I've found to debug IE issues on a mac. This should be higher up. I've found this mimics IE behavior well enough to avoid VM instillations and makes my life much easier.

Comment: This does not emulate IE, it just changes the User Agent header send to web servers

Answer (score 1):

The modern.IE link doesn't work anymore, but Microsoft has virtual machine downloads available for [IE versions 8-11 and Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

Answer (score 0):

Off late I heard about this awesome software Sauce labs (https://saucelabs.com/) which allows you to test your code cross-browser, cross OS.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is virtualbox (free) and a dev copy of Windows8 (free). I just did it now. I followed [this tutorial](https://centroy.com/blog/testing-internet-explorer-mac-its-actually-quite-easy). It took about 30 mins to do on 1 try. https://centroy.com/blog/testing-internet-explorer-mac-its-actually-quite-easy